Snowflake query execution is getting rolled back
I'm trying upload dataframe on to snowflake. The table is getting create but the data is not getting populated.
This is the code I'm using
        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame([('Mark', 10), ('Luke', 20), ('Mark1', 78), ('Luk2e', 20)], columns=['name', 'balance'])
            df.to_sql(
                name=table_name.lower(), con=engine, schema=schema_name,
                if_exists=if_exists, index=False, index_label=None,
                method=pd_writer
            )
        except Exception:
            traceback.format_exc()

Here are the log. Every query is getting rolled back. Not sure what's happening
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,003|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [select current_database(), current_schema();]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,350|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,350|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,351|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,675|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,676|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:36,677|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,063|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,063|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,064|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [DESC TABLE /* sqlalchemy:_has_object */ "Employee26".employee]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,386|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,400|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,788|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,788|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:37,788|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,120|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,120|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,122|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [CREATE TABLE "Employee26".employee ( name TEXT, balance BIGINT )]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,470|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,473|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,806|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,807|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:38,807|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query: [ROLLBACK]
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:39,175|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor query execution done
user|INFO|2024-08-01 10:37:39,175|cursor.snowflake.connector.cursor Number of results in first chunk: 1

